# Choice of Variables for Linear Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear, predictor

Say, I have a dependent variable $Y$ that I want to model with a linear regression and independent variables $X_i$.
I am assuming that two of my independent variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ have an effect on $Y$.
I want to model the variable $Y$ at a time $t_3$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are collected at a time $t_2$.
I am wondering about the following problem:
In what cases would it make sense to include a variable $Y'$ (that represents the same variable as $Y$ that I want to model) collected at a time $t_1$ as an independent variable.
When collecting the data, I was thinking that this might improve the predictive power of my model $Y^{t_3} = \alpha_1 X^{t_2}_1 + \alpha_2 X^{t_2}_2 + \alpha_3 Y^{t_1}$.
However, now I am wondering what implicit assumptions I make about the model.
More specifically, how does the model $Y^{t_3} = \alpha_1 X^{t_2}_1 + \alpha_2 X^{t_2}_2$ differ from the one above.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your model, which contains the $Y$ variable at time $t_1$, looks like a *time series analysis* using a lag $t_3 - t_1$. Have you looked into *time series analysis*?

Comment: In fact, I only have data at $t_1$ and $t_3$ and not for any $t_i, i > 3$.

Comment: I wonder what is your goal. Before you "measure" you only know the inputs $X_1$ and $X_2$. If you are allowed to first measure $Y(t_1)$ and then predict $Y(t_3)$ then use $Y(t_1)$ as input parameter. However, often we want to predict $Y(t_3)$ by using only $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: As @Semoi said, this is more a substantial question, it depends on what is your goal. Do you want to find out how (t2) X1 and X2 predict Y as such, or do you want to find yout how they predict Y when controlling for T1 Y? You can also consider running and reporting both analyses.